# Paramiko and Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, putty, paramiko

Am trying to connect to Google Cloud Engine via SSH Paramiko.
I got this message :

```
import paramiko
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("key_from_gcp/mykey.ppk")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print "connecting"
c.connect( hostname = "123.05.5.5", username = "ubuntu", pkey = k )
print "connected"
commands = [ "/home/ubuntu/firstscript.sh", "/home/ubuntu/secondscript.sh" ]
for command in commands:
    print "Executing {}".format( command )
    stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
    print stdout.read()
    print( "Errors")
    print stderr.read()
c.close()



resulted error is "paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file"
```

Question:
  1) How to change PPK file to PEM file ?
  2) Is there any other fix needed.

Note, PEM file connection works well with AWS.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command to use if you want to create a .pem file:

```
puttygen private_key.ppk -O private-openssh -o priv_p.pem
```