# SSH to Google Cloud VM via paramiko: Authentication Error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to connect to a Virtual Machine via SSH. I've created a key using `ssh keygen`, added the SSH Key in Compute Engine's Metadata, and I can run a local terminal command to use the ssh key to connect into the VM. But when I try to use paramiko in a python project, I get `AuthenticationException: Authentication failed` at the `client.connect()` step. I'm not quite sure why it's not working.

Here's my code, can anyone double check my parameters:

- SSH_KEY_PATH = C:/Users/user123/.ssh/this_project_key
- HOST = External IP address of the VM (taken from GCP)
- MYUSER = username taken from Compute Engine > Metadata > SSH Keys

```py
import os
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy


def sftp_test():
    client = SSHClient()
    client.load_host_keys(os.getenv("SSH_KEY_PATH"))
    client.load_system_host_keys()

    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())

    client.connect("HOST", username="MYUSER")

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("hostname")
    print(stdout)
    client.close()
```

Comment: 1) Can you connect using the same key with an SSH client? 2) Connect to the remote system. The SSH server logs will indicate why the key was rejected. Also go to that user's home directory. Check if the public key is stored in the .ssh directory.

Comment: Set up fist properly your ssh key, and indicate the correct path for your .ssh directory path. You may want to check this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689204/paramiko-and-google-cloud), for reference.